# ByteBufferBackedInputStream refill ByteBuffer

Tags: java, inputstream

I am reading from a file and copying to ByteBuffer. Next, ByteBufferBackedInputStream is initialized with ByteBuffer.

What is the right way to refill the buffer of ByteBufferBackedInputStream?
After reading all the bytes from ByteBufferBackedInputStream, I have to have discard old buffer contents and fill with new  ByteBuffer.

Comment: Why are you using `ByteBufferBackedInputStream`? You seem to be reading from a file, not a `ByteBuffer`, so why are you using that?

Comment: File is over the network and for fast processing I am buffering.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You don't get any speed increase from storing the bytes in a `ByteBuffer` in between.

Comment: Accessing local cache will be faster than I/o call over network. What r the better ways of doing the same?

Comment: Introducing your local cache will add time to the IO, not remove it. Instead of "read, process, store" you want to do "read, store in a ByteBuffer, process, store". `ByteBufferBackedInputStream` is basically a `ByteArrayInputStream`, except the backing storage is a `ByteBuffer` instead of `byte[]`. Would you introduce a `ByteArrayInputStream` into your model for "improved performance"? I didn't think so.